# Java : Creating `List` from `Multimap`

Tags: java, recursion, code-cleanup

I want to arrange values in `Multimap` in a ordered `List`. Where in all the key will be at the left side and all the values will be at right side. I have used recursion to achieve this. But for that I have to pass `List` to that recursive function which returns `void` but the `List` gets modified in that function which I don't like, is there any way to improve this?

Following is my example code

```
private static void getChilds(String col, List<String> list, Multimap<String, String> map) {
        list.add(col);
        Collection<String> String = map.get(col);
        if (!String.isEmpty()) {
            String.stream().forEach(col1 -> getChilds(col1, list, map));
        }
    }

    private static List<String> getList(Multimap<String, String> map) {
        Set<String> strings = map.keySet();
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String string : strings) {
            if (!map.containsValue(string)) {
                getChilds(string, list, map);
            }
        }
        return list;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayListMultimap<String, String> map = ArrayListMultimap.create();
        map.put("P1", "P2");
        map.put("P1", "P3");
        map.put("P1", "P4");
        map.put("P3", "P5");
        map.put("P3", "P6");
        map.put("P7", "P8");
        map.put("P7", "P9");
        System.out.println(getList(map));
    }

Output : [P1, P2, P3, P5, P6, P4, P7, P8, P9]
```

Please suggest if there is any nice way with which I will not break any principle of clean code and still get the desired result.

## Update

So if we put a new entry in the map like

```
map.put("P10", "P1");
```

then corresponding change in the output would be

```
Output : [P7, P8, P9, P10, P1, P2, P3, P5, P6, P4]
```

Comment: Have you tried TreeMultimap?? will it not do what you expect??

Comment: your question does not make sense.  there is no left side of a List.

Comment: @DwB does it makes sense to you after checking output.

Answer (score 0):

All the keys on the left and all the values on the right of the list:

```
List<String> result = new LinkedList<String>();
for (Entry<String, String> entry : map.entries()) 
{
    if (!result.contains(entry.getValue()))
    {
        result.addLast(entry.getValue());
    }
    if (!result.contains(entry.getKey()))
    {
        result.addFirst(entry.getKey());
    }
}
```

If you don't like that list get's modified inside a method. Before issuing that method create a copy of that list and pass a copy instead of original.

```
List<String> copy = new ArrayList<>(original);
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is a terrible solution for most problems; including this one.

Try a non-clown solution (assuming guava multimap):

```
Set<String> keySet = multiMap.keySet();
List<String> returnValue = new LinkedList<String>();

for (String currentKey : keySet)
{
    Collection<String> values = multiMap.get(currentKey);
    returnValue.add(currentKey);
    returnValue.addAll(values);
}
```

Comment: `P3` here is a key as well as value... so this approach would fail adding `P3` twice in the list.

Comment: use a sorted set instead of a linked list.

Comment: The code that I have provided is not the real code.. its just a representation so sorting wouldn't work here.

Comment: if sorting is not important, but set functionality is still important, us an ordered set.

Comment: I think this approach won't work because the original code seems to implement a pre-order depth-first flattening of an n-ary graph. Assume: P1 -> (P3, P4), P3 -> (P5, P4), P4 -> (P6) - the output should be "P1 P3 P5 P4 P6 P4 P6"

Comment: the original output example does not support the "depth-first flattening" interpretation.  The updated output (with P10) is closer to a map walking output, but gives no indication of the starting point.

Comment: I tried both the original and your version (I think you're replacing getList() itself?) for my example: Your output is "[P1, P3, P4, P3, P5, P4, P4, P6]" where it should be "[P1, P3, P5, P4, P6, P4, P6]". A tricky part is that the map essentially contains multiple trees: top-level getChild() is called for every key which does not have a value, i.e. for every node without a parent - P3 and P4 in my example do not satisfy this condition, but they may be called multiple times as part of the traversal.

Answer (score 0):

I think in a case like this, using an in-out parameter like `list` could be justified if it makes the overall process more readable, and/or provides performance advantages (fewer memory allocations). A 'clean' approach where each `getChilds()` call returns a fresh list which the caller then combines with the others, comes at the price of additional memory allocations and copies.

The alternative, if you insist on using streams, could maybe be to use mapTo().reduce() on the stream: let `getChilds()` return a fresh List, and let reduce() combine them all into one.

Personally, if I were to write `getChilds()` as a function, I'd write a normal loop here and accumulate the results by hand:

```
private static List<String> getChilds(String col, Multimap<String, String> map) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(col);
    Collection<String> values = map.get(col);
    for (String val : values) {
        list.addAll(getChilds(val, map);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Note: This code is not safe against cycles.

But code style aside: @DwB raises the good point that by collapsing the whole map into a single flat list, you lose all information about the actual key->(value...) relations. The output "[ P8, P6, P4, P5]" can be produced by "P8 -> (P6), P4 -> (P5)", or by "P8 -> (P6, P4, P5)". The code can be made nicer, but is the result in its current form actually useful?

Comment: I think better to aviod create  lists recursively.

Comment: There are pros and cons to both using an 'outside' single list, and recursive aggregation. Thanks for reminding me - let me make that clearer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private static List<String> getChilds(String col, Multimap<String, String> map) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(col);
        map.get(col).forEach(s->list.addAll(getChilds(s,  map)));
        return list;
    }

    private static List<String> getList(Multimap<String, String> map) {
        Set<String> strings = map.keySet();
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String string : strings) {
            if (!map.containsValue(string)) {
                list.addAll(getChilds(string, map));
            }
        }
        return list;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayListMultimap<String, String> map = ArrayListMultimap.create();
        map.put("P1", "P2");
        map.put("P1", "P3");
        map.put("P1", "P4");
        map.put("P3", "P5");
        map.put("P3", "P6");
        map.put("P7", "P8");
        map.put("P7", "P9");
        map.put("P10", "P1");
        System.out.println(getList(map));
    }
```